# Array and curve modifier causing mesh to break

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

What I have done so far is model a segment of the ring, so that I can then use a curve and array modifier to duplicate it around the curve. However, when I do this, pieces of the mesh separate from the segment. **Note** they were all originally separate meshes, I joined them together using `Ctrl-J`.

[image: Mesh Seperation]

This is what I'm trying to achieve [image: Halo Ring]

As you can see from the above image, the detail that I have added to the base of the segment has separated after using the array and curve modifiers. If it's of any use, I have also attached a copy of the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: What is happening here: the mesh vertices tend to align to the curve. This is done per vertex. As your model contains vertices at different position along the mesh, edges are making an arc along the curve. So the mesh parts are separated. Knowing that, there are 2 possibilities: do you want a perfect circle or do you want a approximated one made of 19 segments (like in your file)?

Comment: Currently it just has 19 segments to keep it at a smaller size, I’ll scale it up later if I can find a solution. Yes, I do want to try and achieve a perfect circle :)

Comment: For a perfect circle you need to add more slices to your mesh. This is the same principle for the circle or sphere object: the more vertices, the more it looks like a perfect circle or sphere...

Comment: And will this fix the problem with the other pieces falling off of the segment?

Comment: More or less. I mean, as said before, a "perfect" circle is always an approximation.